# SQL Next not advancing cursor

Tags: sql, go, go-sqlmock

I have a function that I used to iterate over a result set from a query:

```golang
func readRows(rows *sql.Rows, translator func(*sql.Rows) error) error {
    defer rows.Close()

    // Iterate over each row in the rows and scan each; if an error occurs then return
    for shouldScan := rows.Next(); shouldScan; {
        if err := translator(rows); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    // Check if the rows had an error; if they did then return them. Otherwise,
    // close the rows and return an error if the close function fails
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

The `translator` function is primarily responsible for calling `Scan` on the `*sql.Rows` object. An example of this is:

```
readRows(rows, func(scanner *sql.Rows) error {
    var entry gopb.TestObject

    // Embed the variables into a list that we can use to pull information out of the rows
    scanned := []interface{}{...}

    if err := scanner.Scan(scanned...); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    entries = append(entries, &entry)
    return nil
})
```

I wrote a unit test for this code:

```
// Create the SQL mock and the RDS reqeuster
db, mock, _ := sqlmock.New()
requester := Requester{conn: db}
defer db.Close()

// Create the rows we'll use for testing the query
rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"id", "data"}).
                AddRow(0, "data")

// Verify the command order for the transaction
mock.ExpectBegin()
mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta("SELECT `id`, `data`, FROM `data`")).WillReturnRows(rows)
mock.ExpectRollback()

// Attempt to get the data
data, err := requester.GetData(context.TODO())
```

However, it appears that `Next` is being called infinitely. I'm not sure if this is an `sqlmock` issue or an issue with my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `for rows.Next() {`.

Comment: ... this is because the `for <init>; <cond>; <post> {` form of a `for` statement executes the `<init>`, as its name suggests, only once. Alternatively you could use `for shouldScan := rows.Next(); shouldScan; shouldScan = rows.Next() {`, although I do not know of a good reason to do so.

Comment: See https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements for more details.

Comment: Sorry, I debugged this myself and realized that I had forgotten to update the loop invariant. I will change it to use `for rows.Next() {` instead